# I want to make a new android project in eclipse and when I click finish, it gives me this error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting following error while creating new project on android studio.

> C:\Users\Nisar Khan\workspace\firstt\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: you better Provide the code you Worked with along with the Error

Comment: thankyou for your respose. my sdk was not properly installed. now its working :) @Prasad

Answer (score 0):

Here It is step to solve this type of error in ecllipse.

**Follow this step:**

1. Right Click on the supporting library
2. Click on Properties
3. On the left side click on "Android"
4. Select the right "Android 5.0 - API 21" and click OK
5. Clean the support library: Project -> Clean

It hope it works for you...

Comment: thankyou for your respose. my sdk was not properly installed. now its working :)